# How does StringBuilder reverse work in Java?

Tags: java, string, palindrome

I am trying to solve this leetcode question
https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-linked-list/ , but running into trouble with strings and string builders. For some reason, "12".equals"21" -> returns true.

I tried converting from string builder to string, and just using stringbuilder.

```
class Solution {
public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    while (head != null) {
        s.append(head.val);
        head = head.next;
    }
    String a = s.reverse().toString(); 
    String b = s.toString(); 
    return a.equals(b);
}
}
```

It fails on "12" test case, and returns true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StringBuilder `reverse` does not produce a new StringBuilder instance. It causes the underlying characters of the current StringBuilder to be reversed. So,

```
String a = s.reverse().toString(); 
String b = s.toString();
```

The second `s.toString()` is operating on the reversed `StringBuilder`.

you have to do

```
String original = s.toString(); 
String reversed = s.reverse().toString();
return original.equals(reversed);
```

Comment: Or just don't use StringBuilder here and stick to good ol immutable strings. The performance difference likely won't matter if there is one here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes if the linked list is not large.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one using only 2 StringBuilders instead of 3 and doesn't use the built-in reversed method. Instead, the while loop traverses through the linked list, appends the current node to the `original` StringBuilder, and inserts the current node at the front of the `reversed` StringBuilder. So the built-in insert method helps with reversing the order of the nodes values :

```
public boolean isPalindrome(ListNode head) {
     StringBuilder original = new StringBuilder(), reversed = new StringBuilder();
     ListNode curr = head;
     while (curr != null) {
         original.append(curr.val);
         reversed.insert(0, curr.val);
         curr = curr.next;
     }
     return original.toString().equals(reversed.toString()) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`StringBuilder#reverse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) reverses the character sequence in-place e.g.

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("Hello");
s.reverse();
System.out.println(s); // olleH
```

To preserve the character sequence in the original instance, you need to clone (create a copy) the original instance and reverse the clone e.g.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(a).reverse(); // a is the original instance
return a.toString().equals(b.toString());
```

**Note**: `StringBuilder` does not override `Object#equals` method and therefore even if two `StringBuilder` instances (say, `one` and `other`) have the same content, `one.equals(other)` return `false`. A way to check the equality of the two `StringBuilder` instances is through their `String` representation e.g. `one.toString().equals(other.toString())`.